# is there possible add callback when pop of gesture?

Tags: react-native

I want to do some behaviour after execute `this.props.navigator.pop()` in gesture way, is there possible implement it?

thanks for your time.

regards.

Answer (score -1):

If the statement returns something, you can check for it. Then the code in the if statement would be executed after the fact. Example

```
if(this.props.navigator.pop() == true) {
// code here
}
```

Let me know if this fixes the problem :)

Comment: I try it but return undefined :(